# Minimum needed to use CWindow class methods

Tags: c++, atl

I have some Main Window, application/program `hWnds` from a `EnumWindow` method and want to get information about them. The run of the mill general stuff is enough. Stuff like `IsWindowVisible`, `WindowClassName`, `WindowTextLength`, `WindowText`, `IsWindowUnicode`, `Rect`, `AppDesktopid`, and `AppDesktopRect`.

Want to use `CWindow` for this, as in:

```
CWindow w_Clss(hWnd);
w_Clss.Attach(hWnd);
```

then use the `CWindow` methods like in `CWnd`…

```
w_Clss.IsWindowUnicode();
w_Clss.WindowRect();
```

Knowing that `CWindow` is a wrapper for `ATL`, I proceeded to just declare a `CWindow` object and go from there. Didn't work.

What is the minimum code needed in order for me to obtain program info the `CWindow` way-in stdafx.h, etc?

My program already does Win32 APIs… Since `CWnd` methods are essentially wrappers for Win32 APIs, using those would be redundant. In progressing in my quest… I want to use `CWindow` methods as above.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing that CWindow is a wrapper for ATL, I proceeded to just declare a CWindow object and go from there. Didn't work.
>   What is the minimum code needed in order for me to obtain program info the CWindow way-in stdafx.h, etc?

`CWindow` should work the way you wanted.

```
#include <atlwin.h>
using namespace ATL;
// ...
HWHD hWindow = ... // window handle you get from somewhere
CWindow Window(hWindow);
RECT Position;
Window.GetWindowRect(&Position); // Window is already good enough to have 
                                 // its methods called
```

Comment: That's what I thought... I put in:HWND Lcl_hWnd;
 CWindow Window(Lcl_hWnd);   
 RECT Position;
 Window.GetWindowRect(&Position); and the program would not compile. Error messages received are: C2065: 'CWindow' : undeclared identifier \n  
Error 4 error C2065: 'Window' : undeclared identifier \n
Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Window' \n error C2228: left of '.GetWindowRect' must have class/struct/unionerror \n error C3861: 'Window': identifier not found 
 6 IntelliSense: identifier "CWindow" is undefined

Comment: That's what I thought... I put in:    HWND Lcl_hWnd;    CWindow Window(Lcl_hWnd);    RECT Position;     Window.GetWindowRect(&Position); and the program would not compile. Error messages received are: C2065: 'CWindow' : undeclared identifier   Error 4 error C2065: 'Window' : undeclared identifier   Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Window'  error C2228: left of '.GetWindowRect' must have class/struct/unionerror  error C3861: 'Window': identifier not found  IntelliSense: identifier "CWindow" is undefined    Using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: One thing is that you might need namespace ATL (see updated code), and another is that you might possibly be using Express version of visual Studio which does not have ATL with it.

Comment: Yep, that did it....   <br/>   Put first two lines at top of .cpp file.  <br/>  It's compiling and running.  <br/>Great <br/>  p.s. sorry for the formatting above. Trying to format now as I type.

Comment: ummmm...  It looks like this technique works, but only for the first loop.   In reading further, it seems that CWindow and CWnd don't play together too well. This is because they both are base-type classes used to create Windows and Dialogs.   Another possible alternative is to use CWindow / ATL / or WTL in a Dll. Doing research on this as we speak.

Comment: Instead of `using namespace ATL;` you can replace `CWindow` with `ATL::CWindow`.